# Creating an instance without calling the constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, d

I'd like to create an instance, inject a couple of fields and only then call the constructor on that instance.

Example:

```
class Foo {
    int a = 50;
    int b;

    this() {
        assert(a == 50 && b == 10);
    }
}

...

Foo bar = ???;
bar.b = 10;
bar.this();
```

Generally, `Foo` might have multiple overloaded constructors.
What's the nicest way to do this, without interfering with the garbage collector and other language mechanisms?

---

EDIT: Most responses I've gotten so far were along the lines of "why the hell would you want to do that?!"

I'm currently using such @Annotation-driven system for 2 things: automated configuration loading and automated dependency injection. Both have shown to be big productivity gains for me so far and they also work wonders for responsibility decoupling. (see also: [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))

Though perhaps uncommon in D, similar approaches are widely used in other languages such as Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you should change your constructor to accept those arguments.

But if you really want to, you can break up "bar = new Foo();" into three steps:

- Allocate the memory with the appropriate size (`__traits(classInstanceSize`)
- Initialize the memory with the appropriate contents (`typeid().init` - this holds values for like your a=50, the pointer to the virtual table, etc.)
- Call the constructor

And, of course, returning the new reference.

```
import core.memory; // for GC.malloc
enum size = __traits(classInstanceSize, Foo); // get the size
auto memory = GC.malloc(size)[0 .. size]; // alloc mem and slice it for bounds checking
memory[] = typeid(Foo).init[]; // initialize the memory

Foo foo = cast(Foo) memory.ptr; // we can now cast it to the reference

foo.b = 10; // here's your special line

foo.__ctor(); // and now call the constructor. Can pass any arguments here, D will handle the overloads normally

assert(foo.a == 50); // ensure everything worked
assert(foo.b == 10);
assert(typeid(foo) == typeid(Foo));

// BTW don't use the variable memory anymore - only use the typed Foo instance
```

Breaking down the steps like this also lets you replace the allocation method, if you want. Phobos' `std.conv.emplace` function performs steps 2 and 3 in a single function, to make that easier with custom allocation.

But since you want to insert code between steps 2 and 3, you gotta do it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I've pretty much decided against going this way. Passing everything through the constructor is, of course, possible, but becomes quite a nuisance if you want to wire up 5+ instance fields (though you could argue that a single class shouldn't really have that many dependencies); I'll just keep using an explicit initialization method that's called after the injection is done.

Comment: It might help to make a struct of the members, then just pass the struct to the ctor (which can, in turn, simply assign it to a member variable)